# I have python 2.7 and 3.6 installed on my mac. How to find the version of pip associated with Python3?

Tags: python, pip

I tried using `pip --version` but it will give me the version of only pip associated with python and not python3.

Comment: Have you tried `pip3`. Or else which `python3` and then `/path/to/python3parentdir/pip` as pip for python3 is normally in the same directory as its python

Comment: Also, `python3 -m pip` will always pick the pip associated with the Python installation you just invoked.

Comment: Hi, using pip3 worked.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `pip3 --version`. Normally pip3 is the symlink to the pip associated with Python3. If that doesn't work, please provide more details as to how you installed the python versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the following command, where you can update the program `python` to whatever python program you have

```
python -m pip --version
```